# How to add empty row depending on condition in report builder

Tags: sql, report, builder

I have specific report that i need to create. I have two tables, one that has data of jobs in my company and other that has data of people who work there. In table of jobs there is a data field that contains data of how many people can work on some job (name of job and 1, 2 or other number of people). I need report that will show a name of the job and then list of people that work on that job BUT , and this is problem, if there are less people then job places I need to add empty row for every empty job place. example:

```
job name 1 = 3 places
job name 2 = 4 places
```

Report:

```
JOB NAME 1
---------------------- 
WORKING MAN NAME 1   
WORKING MAN NAME 2   
--- empty place ---  

JOB NAME 2
----------------------
WORKING MAN NAME 1   
WORKING MAN NAME 2   
--- empty place --- 
--- empty place ---
```

I forgot to mention that I am working with DB2 database on IBM system Z and for building reports I am using Visual Studio 10. My two tables are:

JOB:  job_id, job_name, job_num_places

WORKER: worker_id, worker_name, job_id

I am joining tables on job_id

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH JobPositions AS (
    SELECT 'Job1' AS JobName, 3 AS Positions
  UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Job2', 4 AS Positions
)
,Workers AS (
    SELECT 'Worker1' AS WorkerName, 'Job1' AS JobName
  UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Worker2' AS WorkerName, 'Job1' AS JobName
  UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Worker3' AS WorkerName, 'Job2' AS JobName
)
-- Real query starts here.
-- Create a line for each position in each job
, JobPositionNumber AS (
    SELECT JobName, Positions, 1 AS PositionNumber
    FROM JobPositions
  UNION ALL
    SELECT JobName, Positions, PositionNumber + 1
    FROM JobPositionNumber
    WHERE PositionNumber < Positions
)
-- Number the workers from 1 and up per job
, WorkerPositionNumber AS (
    SELECT WorkerName
          ,JobName
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY JobName
                              ORDER BY WorkerName) AS PositionNumber
    FROM Workers
)
-- Now just join numbered jobs with numbered workers
SELECT JobPositionNumber.JobName
      ,CASE WHEN WorkerPositionNumber.WorkerName IS NULL 
            THEN '--- empty place ---' 
            ELSE WorkerName 
       END AS WorkerName 
FROM JobPositionNumber
     LEFT JOIN WorkerPositionNumber
         ON JobPositionNumber.JobName = WorkerPositionNumber.JobName
            AND JobPositionNumber.PositionNumber = WorkerPositionNumber.PositionNumber
ORDER BY JobPositionNumber.JobName
        ,JobPositionNumber.PositionNumber
```

Comment: this is not really the answer I was looking for but thanks anyway. I forgot to mention that I am working with DB2 database on IBM system Z and for building reports I am using Visual Studio 10. So I think that this won't work, one of reasons there is no row_number function.

Comment: Windowing function row_number() is part of sql 2003. Should be supported by DB2.

Comment: yes you are right, my mistake. We had older version of DB2 until a month ago, so I am still getting used to new DB2 9 and additional functions